# is it possible in html to make width with 2 size types?

Tags: html, css, web, width

I'm learning html and, I asked can you make width with 2 size types or more, like I want width to be 10px+3vw it isn't possible like that but is there a way like typecasting or something to make it work, since I know 3 types of sizing width 1-XX% ,2-XXpx and 3-XXvw can you use the three of them in a single width attribute to have full control on its width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()).

```
width: calc(10px + 3vw);
```

You can go nuts with calc and supply as many inputs as you want.

```
width: calc(10px + 3vw + 6vmin + 4% + 1em);
```

It also supports other basic arithmetic operations.

```
width: calc(100% / 7);
```

```css
div
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: calc(10px + 3vw);
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: When I asked my doctor in college he said "I don't know", Thank you your answer was perfect.